# Getting Status: "Not Acceptable" while trying to update a variant price form Rest API Admin Shopify in Airtable Scripts

Tags: javascript, shopify, fetch-api, airtable

this is my first question here in SO, so thanks to any one that help me with this problem.

Basically im trying to update in a PUT request a variant price. I'm using Airtbale scripting to run a javascript, and on this script i fetch the info to call the api and make the update.

```js
var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "variant": {
    "price": "1011",
    "compare_at_price": "1011"
  }
});

console.log(raw);

var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("X-Shopify-Access-Token", api_token);
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

const params = {
  method:'PUT',
  headers:myHeaders,
  body: raw,
};

const url = 
`https://tryp-mexico.myshopify.com/admin/admin/api/2022-04/variants/42242378334462.json`

const response = await fetch(url,params);

console.log(response);
```

When i try tu run this update on Postman, it works well. But here im getting:

{type: "basic", url: "https://tryp-mexico.myshopify.com/admin/admin/api/2022-04/variants/42242378334462.json", status: 406, statusText: "Not Acceptable", ok: false…}

¡Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: There are a bunch of grammatical mistakes in your statements. Please consider correcting them.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL has "admin" twice.

```
const url = 
`https://tryp-mexico.myshopify.com/admin/admin/api/2022-04/variants/42242378334462.json`
```

Are you using a variable for the Shop URI, that possibly already has `/admin` in it?

This is the correct URI format for variants:

`https://tryp-mexico.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/variants/42242378334462.json`

Comment: Begginers mistake. Thanks for make me notice this fast :)

Comment: it'd be great if you could please mark the answer as right if it's helped you then :)